# Как скачать файл?

Tags: файлы, php, загрузка

Есть файлик с кучей ссылок вида "http://www.ex.ua/load/********", по которым скачиваются аудио-файлы (если ссылку забить в браузере или использовать с командой wget). Безуспешно пробую сделать скрипт для выгрузки этих файлов из сети (в массиве $links содержатся ссылки):

вариант 1:

```
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
        $fs = fopen($link, 'rb');
        $file = fopen('files/'.($key + 1), 'w');
        if ($fs && $file) {
            echo($link.' is downloading.<br/>');
            while (!feof($fs)) {
                fwrite($file, fread($fs, 4096));
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        fclose($fs);
    }
```

вариант 2:

```
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
        $c = curl_init($link);
        $file = fopen('files/'.($key + 1), 'wb');
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);
        fclose($file);
    }
```

вариант 3:

```
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
        if (!copy($link, 'files/'.($key + 1))) {
            echo $link.' copy\'s error<br/>';
        }
    }
```

вариант 4:

```
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
        $ch = curl_init($link);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)');
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $fh = fopen('files/'.($key + 1), 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $output);
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

вариант 5:

```
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
        file_put_contents('files/'.($key + 1), file_get_contents($link));
    }
```

И ни один вариант не делает того, что нужно - не скачивает требуемые файлы. При использовании варианта 1, 3, 5 полученные файлы содержат html/css код страницы, на которой содержится ссылка на требуемый файл. При использовании вариантов 2, 4 полученные файлы содержат

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Так я и не разобрался как же скачать файлы. Может, подскажет кто-нибудь? :)

UPD.

Скрины запрос/ответов при выгрузке файла браузером:

http://hkar.ru/xgKC

http://hkar.ru/xgKD

http://hkar.ru/xgKE

ЗЫ. Не получается выложить в удобном формате (в виде превьюшек/картинок), поэтому помещаю ссылки на скрины.

Comment: Подозреваю что страница с которой пытаетесь скачать использует редирект на JS. Для того чтобы вам дали полный ответ, необходимо выложить заголовки и тело ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь программировать просто подставляя в исходный код найденные в Google части программы? Попробуйте прочитать про используемые вами функции, например, на php.net

**Обновление**

Yandex: wget по маске

**Обновление**

С сервера может отдаваться страница-заглушка, если запрашивающий музыку клиент не определен, как какой- то браузер. При побайтовом чтении заголовок на сервер с музыкой отправляется с идентификацией вашего сервера, я думаю. Посмотрите примеры htaccess защиты от кражи картинок с сайта. В вашем случае помочь может только CURL или какая-то сайтокачалка типа teleport pro.

Comment: спасибо, вы очень помогли :)

Comment: @alexelev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Yandex: wget по маске

Comment: я этот скрипт запускаю у себя на винде, мне тут wget без надобности. И мне интересно, почему НИ ОДИН из использованных методов не дает необходимого результата. Ладно, про curl я мало что знаю, вполне предполагаю, что не установил какие-либо нужные опции в set_opt (о чем косвенно намекается в результате - bad request), однако при побайтовом чтении что может идти не так?

Comment: то, что у меня изображено в варианте 4 не позволяет отдающему серверу определить клиента? Или вместо Googlebot'a лучше передать описание браузера?
UPD.
Изменение CURLOPT_USERAGENT приводит к тому же результату...

Comment: Да, посмотрите заголовки, отправляемые браузером и установите такие же значения в настройках CURL. Если браузером вы получить файл можете, то и с помощью CURL все получится. Если на том сервере нет фильтрации по ip хостеров :)